# Recovery Mode Startup Security Utility reporting no administrator accounts found

Tags: macos, recovery-hd

I booted into recovery mode and started up the Startup Security Utility - but says no administrator found.

I am the administrator. I booted normally and checked user&groups and was listed as Admin. Even though there was no account name listed above the 'Admin' text. But it does list the account/login name on the login page.

When I boot into recovery mode, I assume the recovery partition is active and there's no admin accounts in that partition???? not sure. But there is in the main macos partition on the HD.

This is mac mini w/ T2 chip and Ventura 13.2

Comment: Recovery is not the sane boot image as your regular macOS.  When it starts, there are no accounts, just root and it’s already signed in.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I created a backup of the internal disk to an external disk and I was trying to boot from the external disk to test. And the system was telling me that for security reasons I need to enable boot from external usb - and that gets done via the SSU.

Comment: You don’t do that in Recovery.  You have to hold the power button until you get start up options

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more pls. So basically I need to add admin account to the recovery partition right???

Comment: No.  Recovery is just for that…recovery. It has only the basics.  To boot and get the start up options, turn off the press and hold the power button until you see the options menu. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: ok I'll look at that link. but recovery mode also allows you to boot from a specific HD from the menu.

Comment: I did that and got the startup options and I selected the external USB drive. I got the message "Security settings do not allow this Mac to use an external startup disk." It then tells me to boot in recovery mode and start up SSU. When I start that up, it tells me no administrator accounts found.

Comment: Is your an account an admin?

Comment: yes it is. it's my personal mini and I checked it's listed as admin. Thinking about this issue it seems that the authorization to allow external usb boot shouldn't be stored on any disk partition - it should be stored on non-volatile mem on the computer itself. This mini has T2. That makes more sense. If this authorization was stored on a disk - they can be swapped out.

Comment: When I boot into recovery mode, I don't get a login prompt. Some sites report to login. I think maybe that could be the problem. https://appleinsider.com/inside/macos-ventura/tips/how-to-make-an-external-bootable-working-drive-in-macos-ventura

Comment: Recovery won’t have a login prompt. That’s by design

Comment: Any ideas when I start SSU, what administrator not found is referring to. I've got 2 desktop login admin accounts. I don't remember setting any special firmware/EFI passwords either. Other videos i've seen don't seem to run into this roadblock.

Comment: How are you booting into Recovery?  Just `Opt-R`, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and solution seems to be very silly.

The issue was that for my admin account, there was no full name set - it was blank.

I entered something in there, restarted SSU and it detected the account.

The kicker is that it looks for a filled out full name and then just displays the username (used for desktop login).

I would think it should be just looking for the account type (i.e. admin).